# INSERT query results in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I'm using Postgres and I'm trying to insert the results of the below SELECT CASE WHEN query in the table rvu_arbeid, but I'm not able to do so. Any suggestions?

```
INSERT 
INTO rvu_arbeid (arb_utd)
    SELECT hvor_oy_arb_utd, hvor_bg_arb_utd,
    CASE 
        WHEN hvor_oy_arb_utd <> '- Velg alternativ -' THEN hvor_oy_arb_utd
        WHEN hvor_bg_arb_utd <> '- Velg alternativ -' THEN hvor_bg_arb_utd
        ELSE 'NA'
    END
    FROM rvu_arbeid
;
```

Comment: are you sure that you don't want an UPDATE instead of an NSERT?

Comment: post sample data what you tried?

Comment: INSERT creates a new record, UPDATE updates an existing record. The manual is good starting point: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-sql.html

Comment: This INSERT statement will fail, because it tries to insert into one column, but SELECT statement returns 3 columns.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I'm thinking `<>` is not a good operator for this as both `hvor_oy_arb_utd` and `hvor_bg_arb_utd` could meet that requirement at the same time.